# How to parse a nested protobuf message, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, protocol-buffers, grpc-python

I created the following protobuf object:

```
message House {
    message Room {
        message Attributes {
            string bed = 1;
            string desk = 2;
        }
    }
    message Kitchen {
        message Attributes {
            string stove = 1;
            string fridge = 2;
        }
    }
    Room room = 1;
    Kitchen kitchen = 2; 
 }
```

I'm trying to initialize a House object using:

```
attributes = House.Room.Attributes(
        bed = "Queen",
        desk = "Office desk"
    )

request = House(
        room=House.Room(
            Attributes = attributes
        ),
        sourceFactAttributes=None
    )
```

However, I keep getting the following error:
`ValueError: Protocol message Room has no "Attributes" field.`

Answer (score 0):

Nesting messages like this can get messy.

You may find it easier to keep everything flat, i.e. have `House`, `Room`, `Attributes` all defined at the top level as messages. See example at end.

Your issue is that the message (type) `Attributes` is defined in the message `House` but isn't then referenced as an field.

This corresponds to what you're doing with `Room` and `Kitchen` where, after defining the message (type), you then define a field that uses the type.

The solution is to add fields to the message `Room` and to the message `Kitchen` for the type `Attributes`, i.e.:

```
message House {
    message Room {
        message Attributes {
            string bed = 1;
            string desk = 2;
        }
        Attributes attributes = 1; // Here
    }
    message Kitchen {
        message Attributes {
            string stove = 1;
            string fridge = 2;
        }
        Attributes attributes = 1; // Here
    }
    Room room = 1;
    Kitchen kitchen = 2; 
}
```

I think this is easier understood as:

```
message House {
    Room room = 1;
    Room kitchen = 2; // Room==Kitchen so define it once
}

message Room {
    Attributes attributes = 1;
}

message Attributes {
    string bed = 1;
    string desk = 2;
}
```

> **NOTE** Flattening the messages also makes the distinction between message definitions and field types clearer. And, in this case, allows us to see that `Room` and `Kitchen` are the same definition and so may benefit from sharing a type.